# How to use in a view an argument like gids[0]=

Tags: organic-groups, views

I have a custom content type that is associated to groups. When I create a new item, the URL is /node/add/content_type?gids[0]=xxx, where xxx is the node id of the organic group whose this content will be associated.
One of the field of this content type is a user reference. I wanted that this reference is restricted to only members of this group.
This should be accomplished easily using "select list" as the widget for the user_reference field and selecting a view which returns just the members of the group as the "View used to select the users:". og_members views seems perfect, but unfortunately it works with urls like /xxx and not ?gids[0]=xxx.
I googled a lot and tried several things, even create a new view from scratch, without success.
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: It helps if you mention your Drupal version!

Comment: it's drupal 6 with views 2

Answer (score 1):

Try [Views Arguments Extras](http://drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras) that lets you set URL params (gid[0], in this case) as arguments. 
You can also "push" arguments to the View at the User-Reference field's settings page. You just need to return the URL param to the View.
You must configure the View accordingly.

```
return $_GET['gid[0]'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the Views Module, but it has a learning curve (well worth studying!). Try the video series at Nodeone.se called Taming the Beast. You will emerge as a guru of Viewdom.

Also, there is a closely related question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15439/how-can-i-use-the-logged-in-users-group-id-as-a-contextual-filter-in-views) to look at.